# How to use swig to generate php interface for c++ so

Tags: php, c++, swig

I have tried a hundred things and I can not get my .so file to interface with php using swig. I can generate the files, then I had to compile Zend and link with that to make the .so but it keeps seg faulting on load now.

Can some one please walk me though how to use swig to generate a PHP interface for a C++ library? The [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) on the swig web site is not helpful.

Comment: i've gotten swig to work with python. not sure how similar the experience is but I can write what I did for that if you are interested.

Comment: From reading the docs its very different to php. I just cant work out how to get it to compile and work.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) seems informative. Have you tried it?

Comment: Me too. I get "Unable to find file 'example.i'" after running "swig -php example.i".

Comment: Did you create the file example.i?

Comment: @Volomike - i had the same issue "Unable to find file 'example.i" . What i did: i opened the terminal an tried to compile the "example.i" file. The issues was that i was not in the same folder where the file was. I fixed it by changing the working directory in the terminal from user@pc_name to user@pc_name/path/to/example.i file

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same situation but then the answer by Gaius clarified that the example.i file must be created first, it is not just a fancy parameter to tell swig the name of your project. [Paragraph 2.3.1 of that guide](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn5)! tells what this example.i file is about.

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example
%{
/* Put headers and other declarations here */
extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);
%}

extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Double check the permissions of the folder your PHP Code residing. I faced the same problem. In fact I was doing some file read/write stuff too in the same directory and I had to set permission to my php project accordingly , otherwise it used to say **No Data Received** and when I see in apache error log I see Segmentation Fault.

So please check. this may help.

And yes the documentation in Swig site is still not much helpful for PHP developers.